GflowNet fails to learn certain rewards
I tried to reduce my problem to the following code:
# Transitions on graph
transitions = {
    # 0: no-op 
    # 1: N 
    # 2: S 
    # 3: W
    # 4: E
    1: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1},
    2: {0: 2, 1: 12, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2},
    3: {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 1},
    4: {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 3},
    5: {0: 5, 1: 13, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 5},
    6: {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 4},
    7: {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 9, 4: 6},
    8: {0: 8, 1: 14, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 8},
    9: {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 9, 3: 10, 4: 7},
    10: {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 9},
    11: {0: 11, 1: 15, 2: 10, 3: 16, 4: 11},
    12: {0: 12, 1: 18, 2: 2, 3: 12, 4: 12},
    13: {0: 13, 1: 19, 2: 5, 3: 13, 4: 13},
    14: {0: 14, 1: 20, 2: 8, 3: 14, 4: 14},
    15: {0: 15, 1: 21, 2: 11, 3: 17, 4: 15},
    16: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 11},
    17: {0: 17, 1: 22, 2: 16, 3: 23, 4: 15},
    18: {0: 18, 1: 18, 2: 12, 3: 25, 4: 18},
    19: {0: 19, 1: 19, 2: 13, 3: 26, 4: 25},
    20: {0: 20, 1: 20, 2: 14, 3: 27, 4: 26},
    21: {0: 21, 1: 21, 2: 15, 3: 22, 4: 27},
    22: {0: 22, 1: 22, 2: 17, 3: 24, 4: 21},
    23: {0: 23, 1: 24, 2: 17, 3: 23, 4: 17},
    24: {0: 24, 1: 22, 2: 23, 3: 24, 4: 22},
    25: {0: 25, 1: 25, 2: 25, 3: 19, 4: 18},
    26: {0: 26, 1: 26, 2: 26, 3: 20, 4: 19},
    27: {0: 27, 1: 27, 2: 27, 3: 21, 4: 20}
}

# Model
class TBModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_hid):
    super().__init__()

    self.mlp_forward = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(TRAJECTORY_LENGTH, num_hid), 
                                     nn.LeakyReLU(),
                                     nn.Linear(num_hid, OUTPUT_DIMS))
    
    self.mlp_backward = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(TRAJECTORY_LENGTH, num_hid), 
                                      nn.LeakyReLU(),
                                      nn.Linear(num_hid, OUTPUT_DIMS))
    
    self.logZ = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1))

  def forward(self, x):
    P_F = self.mlp_forward(x)
    return P_F
  
  def backward(self, x):
    P_B = torch.tensor([(1/INPUT_DIMS)]*INPUT_DIMS)#self.mlp_backward(x) 

    return P_B

# Reward Funcs
def reward_that_model_does_not_learn(trajectory):
  goal_trajectory = [21, 27, 20, 14, 8]
  reward = 0
  for i in range(len(trajectory)):
    if trajectory[i] == goal_trajectory[i]:
      reward = reward + 1
  return torch.tensor(reward)

def reward_that_model_learns(trajectory):
  if trajectory == [21, 27, 20, 14, 8]:
    return torch.tensor([1])
  return torch.tensor([0])


model = TBModel(512)
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),  3e-4)

tb_losses = []
tb_rewards = []
logZs = []
minibatch_loss = 0
minibatch_reward = 0

for episode in tqdm.tqdm(range(NUM_EPOCHS), ncols=40):
  
  gflow_state = torch.zeros(TRAJECTORY_LENGTH)
  state = START_NODE
  total_P_F = 0
  total_P_B = 0
  trajectory = []

  for t in range(TRAJECTORY_LENGTH):
    trajectory.append(state)
    P_F_s = model.forward(gflow_state)
    P_B_s = torch.tensor([(1/5)]) 

    cat = Categorical(logits=P_F_s)
    action = cat.sample()
    _gflow_state = gflow_state.clone()
    _gflow_state[t] = action
    gflow_state = _gflow_state.clone()

    new_state = transitions[state][action.item()]
    total_P_F += cat.log_prob(action)
    total_P_B += torch.log(P_B_s) 

    state = new_state

  reward = reward_that_model_does_not_learn(trajectory)

  loss = (model.logZ + total_P_F - torch.log(reward).clip(-20) - total_P_B).pow(2)
  
  minibatch_loss += loss
  minibatch_reward += reward

  if (episode + 1) % BATCH_SIZE == 0:
    wandb.log({
      "loss": minibatch_loss.item(),
      "reward": minibatch_reward.item()/BATCH_SIZE,
      "Z": model.logZ.item()
    })
    minibatch_loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    opt.zero_grad()
    minibatch_loss = 0
    minibatch_reward = 0

This is my implementation of the GFlowNet. I am using this model to guide an agent through a map with 27 nodes as described by transitions. The GFlowNet samples permutations of actions which will move the agent through the map. At the end of the trajectory, the reward will be computed for the agent. The model is capable of learning an explicit trajectory by the reward reward_that_model_learns. However, the agent has a much more difficult time learning to optimize the reward defined by reward_that_model_does_not_learn. The only difference between the two is one has an all or nothing scoring while the other gives partial credit for a trajectory. I don't see why the model can struggle with one but learn the other because in both cases it deals with the same state space (permutations of actions). It would be good to have some theoretical understanding of why some rewards are harder to learn and how to move forward thanks.
